# How to create new list column values from groupby

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

My goal is to create a new column `c_list` that contains a list after an groupby (without `merge` function): `df['c_list'] = df.groupby('a').agg({'c':lambda x: list(x)})`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
                  {'a': ['x', 'y', 'y', 'x'],
                   'b': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'c': [8, 2, 5, 6]
                  }
                 )
df
```

Initial dataframe

```
    a   b   c
0   x   2   8
1   y   0   2
2   y   0   5
3   x   0   6
```

Looking for:

```
    a   b   c  d
0   x   2   8  [6, 8]
1   y   0   2  [2, 5]
2   y   0   5  [2, 5]
3   x   0   6  [6, 8]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `transform`

```
df['d']=df.groupby('a').c.transform(lambda x : [x.values.tolist()]*len(x))
0    [8, 6]
1    [2, 5]
2    [2, 5]
3    [8, 6]
Name: c, dtype: object
```

Or

```
df['d']=df.groupby('a').c.agg(list).reindex(df.a).values
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Out of curiosity, why the multiplication by len(x) in lambda function ?

Comment: @AdilBlanco transform have the problem , when there is only list , it will explode it by default, so we need the use the list multiple the len of sub-group ~